# Sonata user bundle group roles

Tags: sonata-user-bundle

I have set up sonata user bundle with sonata admin. Now I have user groups that have some roles. I created an "admin" group and assigned ROLE_ADMIN.

Now if i create a user and assign him to this admin group I try to log out and login in admin panel with this user. I'm getting access denied error.

It seems that I need to set user role as ROLE_ADMIN. Group roles does nod work. What good are user groups for if I still have to set a role for individual user?

Or is there a way to make group roles work?

Answer (score 0):

Seems I found the answer. I have to configure sonata_user:

```
sonata_user:
    table:
         user_group:fos_user_user_group
```